# Convert Mysql timestamp to local country time stamp

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

My Server(Tomcat) is at North America and I have my clients in different regions on globe.

Here I got a problem:

```
      select time_stamp from table_name;
         ___________________
        |  time_stamp       |
        ---------------------
        |2015-08-26 20:03:30|
        ---------------------
```

This is time in North America(MySQL is taking server time) but my clients are viewing this value from India/USA in a HTML page.

How to convert this value to my clients local time.

Answer (score 0):

in the Client you set set the time_zone

SET time_zone = timezone;

here you can found details [set time_zone](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/time-zones/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the convert_tz function.

Look this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 2:00:00','US/Eastern','US/Central');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 2:00:00','US/Eastern','US/Central') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2007-03-11 01:00:00                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 3:00:00','US/Eastern','US/Central');
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2007-03-11 3:00:00','US/Eastern','US/Central') |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2007-03-11 02:00:00                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Supporting documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html and this to populate the tables http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html

Comment: You are converting US/Eastern to US/Central then what about remaining places like Japan/India etc